# Can I complete the achievement for stunt jumps?

Tags: achievements, grand-theft-auto-v

At some point the counter for stunt jumps appears to have bugged out. I completed 47 of the 50 stunt jumps (tracking them with the [Achievement Hunter map](http://maps.achievementhunter.com/guides/map/grandtheftautov/thecity)). Now, any of the remaining three jumps I complete, if I complete it successfully, the game says:

> Stunt Jump Completed
>
> undefined

I went ahead and completed the 3 remaining jumps I had to make, and they all gave the same *undefined* response, and the achievement didn't trigger. Is there any known way to fix this bug, or am I out of luck and would need to start a game over?

Comment: try doing them with an online character, I got the achievement that way, although I'm not sure if it combines your single player jumps with your online ones or not.

Answer (score 1):

I've read if you do the Downtown Underground race, you can get credit for 50 jumps off the one jump located during the race. More than a few people simply looped back some 49 times to perform the jump and get the achievement.

I will say that I gave it a quick try in a bike, and it didn't work for me, but others said it worked fine in a car. Hopefully it allows you to knock it out after 3 quick passes.

Here's a video of it in action -

Comment: I think he is asking about single player, in which case this might not work, unless he goes online and does it 50 times of course.

Comment: He references the achievement, which will unlock either the way he was trying to do it, or this way. If he wants the in game Award, then he might be up the proverbial estuary without a means of conveyance.

Comment: I agree the achievement will unlock, but I don't think he can do anything about the 3 broken stunt jumps in his single player game, since this is an online only method.